# ASP.NET MVC site behaves different when accessed remotely

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have deployed my MVC site on IIS server. If I access it using `http://localhost` in URL it works fine.
But if I use machine name/ ip address in the URL, some of the functions are not working properly. I wonder why this is happening. Following are some of the things I am facing

1. I have used JQuery Tab in a dialog box. The dialog box doesn't submit data if the site is accessed remotely.
2. I have used JQuery Month navigator. I could see it is submitting correct month and year during HttpPost controller, but the controller action doesn't redirect according to posted data.

I am clueless on why its behaving like this

```
/* Some code for reference */

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{    
    .....
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="buttonSave" onclick="return     ConfirmSave();" />                        
    </div> 
}

function ConfirmSave() {
    return confirm('You have selected to copy this entry.\n\n This action cannot be rolled back, and each created entry will need to be deleted independently. Are you sure you want to continue?');
}
```

Comment: With `MVC` it's usually the relative URL that creates a problem when deploying from development to live server. BTW a sample code would make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: please post some code of the defected fetures that are accessed remotly

Comment: added some code for reference. This part does not work properly while accessed remotely

Comment: Have you tried accessing the site while an HTTP debugger (such as Fiddler, or the built-in request analyzer for Chrome/Safari)? You could then examine the requests and responses for issues, such as invalid URLs, etc.